# PHP upload only works with certain files (perhaps size dependent)

Tags: php

I'm developing (local, mac) an image (i know, a pdf file is not an image) upload form. I have the following files for my test case:

- `test.jpg`, 500x500px, 8kb, green square
- `tester.jpg`, 6000x6000px, 426kb, green square
- `Screen Shot 2013-09-23 at 12.12.29 .png`, 3360x2100px, 2.3MB, screenshot
- `P1020521.JPG`, 4000x3000px, 2.7MB, picture from a compact camera
- `optimal web design.pdf`, 612×792, 46 pages, 733kb, pdf document

The purpose of the form is to upload an image, check for the dimensions and (if necessary) resize the image to either an max-width of 1200 or max-height of 800 pixels, rename the image and save the file.

When i try to upload the above files, i get these results:

- `test.jpg` gets handled the way it should (i find a renamed 1200x1200 file in my uploads folder)
- `tester.jpg`, doesn't show any output and resizing, but i find a renamed 6000x6000 file in my uploads folder
- `Screen Shot 2013-09-23 at 12.12.29 .png` fails at the `is_uploaded_file()` check
- `P1020521.JPG` fails at the `is_uploaded_file()` check
- `optimal web design.pdf` gets handled the way it should (without resizing ofcourse, php resizing errors), i find a renamed pdf file in my uploads folder

For resizing my images i use [this class](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/), which i've used before and works like a charm.

The thing i don't get is that why certain files are handled the way they should, while others fail the `is_uploaded_file()` check. Am i missing some basic setting here?

I've searched this site and found a this possible solution, `if(is_uploaded_file(realpath($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))){` but that one didn't work out.

Its just a few simple lines of code and i don't get it why it works on some files, but fails on others.

Here is my form:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:file').change(function(){
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>

[..]

<form id="inline-upload-form" method="POST" action="process.image-upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <legend id="main-form-legend">Instellingen
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="defaultInput">
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

process.image-upload.php:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $dir = '/path/to/uploads/';
        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = $_SESSION['user_id'].date("dmYHis").'.'.$extension;
        $uploadfile = $dir.$filename;
        if(is_uploaded_file(realpath($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))){
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
                $resizeObj = new resize($uploadfile);
                $resizeObj -> resizeImage(1200, 800, 'auto');
                $resizeObj -> saveImage($uploadfile, 100);
                echo($uploadfile.' uploaded');
            }else{
                echo('not moved');
            }
        }else{
            echo('not uploaded');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the max_upload_size of your server?

Comment: To show the error code: <?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  //your code
  }
?>

Comment: update `php.ini` file and set `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size `

Comment: Dumb, dit not think of that. Works like a charm now, Thnx!